# Designing Database schema for forms

Tags: database, schema, storage

I am designing a database schema for forms which contains checkboxes,MCQs,True/False.The checkbox fields can be up to 20.I have designed a metadata table which contains the data but i don't think it is the most optimum solution.

---

### # METADATA

-ID

-Type(MCQ/Checkbox)

-Value_selected.

---

### # CheckBoxes

-ID

-Question

-field1

-Field2

-field3

### i have a confusion with this part on how to store multiple fields efficiently.

---

### # MCQ

-ID

-Question

-Field1.

-Field2

---

I hope you get the problem.Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I've seen used recently is to store the Field1, Field2 as a separated string in a text field such as:

```
# MCQ
ID: 1
Question: SomeQuestion
Responses: Field1|Field2|Field3
```

Then in your answer table you would store the selected values separated by the |. A better solution would be to store the responses as a Json string, which would give you flexibility in having values, text and other metadata tied to each response. Something like:

```
{"Responses":[{"value":1,"text":"Field1"},{"value":2,"text":"Field2"}]
```

If you want to really normalize the database you would have responses as a separate table. Something like:

```
#MCQ
MCQId: 1
Question: SomeQuestion

#MCQResponse
MCQId: 1
MCQResponseId: 1
Response: Field1

MCQId: 1
MCQResponseId: 2
Response: Field2
```

Comment: Dude that's an awesome idea..

Answer (score 1):

If is is that you want to the system to create fields then you may want to go with a fully normalized database with tables for each individual object. eg. form_table, form_fields_table, fields_table, fields_options_table, options_table.

This would allow you to use the same structure to create multiple fields of different types and dynamically assign options to them(each field can have multiple options/ each field can have a different number of options). You can then dynamically assign these fields to individual forms. This would be better done with a framework that can manage the relationships than you trying to do it yourself.

If the system does no need to create the forms, then all you would need to save are the form responses, and so you should create the UI for the forms separate from the DB structure. The DB would only need to store the response to the field responses.

Comment: So you think i should go with the snow flake schema instead of star schema?

Comment: Like I said it depends on your needs. From a logical perspective, if the system will need to allow the creation of new forms and also possibly dynamically generate the UI based on the created form (well even if you dont go as far as generating the fields) then you want something scalable and the "snowflake schema", as you put it(just dont like these kinda labels), works better and is easier to maintain. the only issue would be the complexity of your queries as the system gets larger. so you would need to look into a MVC framework that can manage the relationships